# App crashes immediately if not already installed in the device on iOS 10

Tags: xcode, crash, beta, ios10

I bounced against a very troubling issue when porting my app to iOS 10. I had been reinstalling it without problems on already present copies. Yet when I tried to delete it and install it from Xcode, the app quite silently crashed soon after executing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

With the simple final log item:
[access] "<"private">"

If I conversly download it from the published copy on the AppStore and execute it thereafter from Xcode, the app does not crash any longer.
If I execute it on the iPad it even shows a message to enable localization that remains stuck on the window until I reboot the device.
The app also crashes on the simulator.

What might it be and how to know more, given I have no crash report returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App will crash if its accessing any private data like below with out defining them in plist(Getting permission from User)

**Calendar Events**
**Location**

If you are using any like above, then you need to add Privacy statements to `info.plist` file.

Below one is to access Calendar:
`Privacy - Calendars Usage Description = "some text"`

`key` =  `Privacy - Calendars Usage Description`
`value` = `"some Text"`

Comment: Yes, right. I found by searching for the log entry. In my case I missed:

NSCalendarsUsageDescription and
NSMotionUsageDescription

Answer (score 2):

`iOS 10` has continued the privacy policy and has implemented new privacy rules. And we should remember to implement them in our next projects.

For your issue you need to add following line into `info.plist`

```
<!--  Calendars -->
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>
```

Below are the rest of the privacy rules :

```
<!--  Photo Library -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Camera -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Microphone -->
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location -->
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location When In Use -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location Always -->
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Calendars -->
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!-- ⏰ Reminders -->
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Motion -->
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Health Update -->
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Health Share -->
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!-- ᛒ Bluetooth Peripheral -->
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Media Library -->
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>
```

Hope this helps. :)